# Network Error при запросе на сервер через Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

код запроса на клиенте , тестирую на локалке (подключаюсь к localhost:4000) :

```js
export const sendData = data => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(sendDataRequest());
  const url = routes.syncUrl();
  axios.post(url, data)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      dispatch(sendDataSuccess({ responseLink: response.data }));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch(sendDataFailure({ responseError: 'errore del request' }));
    });
};
```

код на стороне сервера , закомментированый вариант с корс заголовками тоже не работает:

```js
export default () => {
  const app = new Express();
  app.use(cors());
  /* app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  }); */

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('tipo qualche link dal server');
  });
  return app;
};
```

Вот собственно ошибка которая вылетает в консоли firefox при попытке запроса :

```js
 Error
​
columnNumber: 15
​
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​
fileName: "file:///home/anehoda/projectImap/dist/main.js"
​
lineNumber: 746
​
message: "Network Error"
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
response: undefined
​
stack: "createError@file:///home/anehoda/projectImap/dist/main.js:746:15\nhandleError@file:///home/anehoda/projectImap/dist/main.js:289:14\n"
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Не понимаю в чем проблема , в интернете повсюду пишут что проблема в corss но у меня нужные заголовки уже присутствуют как видите

Comment: я не шарю в node express, но насколько мне известно, у вас в конфиге отсутствует явно какая-то нужная часть)))

Comment: Это вы по ошибке разшифровали ?

Comment: нет просто видел правильный конфиг на экспресс недавно))

Comment: Ну я тут опубликовал только неоюходимое что бы не засорять но даже этот минимум должен работать судя по документации

Comment: в конфиге явно где то порт прописывался если мне память не отшибает

Comment: ну порт прописывается вот в этой части :app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
    }

    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})  у меня она есть

Comment: например если создать обработку get запроса то через браузер всё работает а вот через axios нет

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился добавлением http:// к url запроса . Было `"localhost:3000/"`
а надо `"http://localhost:3000/"` . get запрос через браузер работал потому что браузер автоматически добавляет http:// к адресу а вот Axios походу нет.